# Azure Search filter all properties of array

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I have a documents in Azure Search that looks like this for example

```
[
{ LabelId: "1,2,4,5" },
{ LabelId: "1,3,5" },
{ LabelId: "1,2,5" }
]
```

Now if I want to search for all documents that might contain 1,3 then I have the following filter

```
LabelId/any(t: search.in(t, '1,3'))
```

This does and OR search, ie if 1 or 3 is in the data it returns the result. However, I want an AND search, so it returns only when 1 AND 3 are available.

Is there filter syntax for this?

Comment: How about next query: `LabelId/any(t: t eq '1') and LabelId/any(t: t eq '3')
`

Answer (score 0):

You can use directly a regular expression in search query instead of filter.

Expression.

`/.*1.*/ AND /.*3.*/`

Using your json array I've created index.

[image]

and below is the output.

[image]

Reason you are not getting using `search.in` is because it checks whether the document value present in the given values.

Example:

In your filter it check `1,3,5` present in `1,3` and not the substring.

You can see that in below query output.

`LabelId/any(t: search.in(t, '1,3,5|1,2,5'))`

Here `|` is the separator between each values, since you document consists `,` i given `|` as separator.

[image]